# client can't send message from separate class

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-studio, client

I created a socket program on android studio. First I create it with on the main class and it is working. With the help of this site I separate the connect and disconnect it works. Now there is a problem when the client send a message on the server. Whenever I put a letter, the output is just a blank space.

> separate class

```
public class SocketClient extends Thread {

String serverm = null;

Socket client;
String Socketdata;
Context context;
String message;
String address;
public boolean mRun = true;
private PrintWriter printwriter;

public SocketClient (String address, Context context, String message  )
{
    this.address = address;
    this.context = context;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    mRun = true;
    try {
        client = new Socket(address, 3818);
        BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        while (mRun) {
            serverm = mBufferIn.readLine();

            if (serverm != null) {
                System.out.println(serverm);
                Socketdata = serverm;
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopSocket()
{
    if(client !=null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            client.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "socket not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void SendSocket()
{
    if (message != null) {
        try {

            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            printwriter.write(message + "\r\n"); // write the message to output stream
            printwriter.flush();

        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, "sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

> Main class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message); // reference to the text field
    Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect); // reference to the connect button
    Disconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect); // reference to the connect button
    Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send); // reference to the send button
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address); // reference to the address

    Disconnect.setOnClickListener(DisconnectOnClickListener);
    Connect.setOnClickListener(ConnectOnClickListener);
    Send.setOnClickListener(SendOnClickListener);
}

//Button Send
OnClickListener SendOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        thread.SendSocket();
        textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
        }

};

//Button Disconnect
OnClickListener DisconnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        thread.stopSocket();
    }

};

//Button Connect
OnClickListener ConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        thread = new SocketClient(editTextAddress.getText().toString(), getApplicationContext(), textField.getText().toString());

        thread.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: `when I send a message on the server. there is no message, it is just a blank space`.  ??????? What do you mean? On the server? Who is sending a message? Where is that blank spacd. Please explain much better who does what.

Comment: thread.sendSocket is executed on the main thread. You will have a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Look in the LogCat.

Comment: I use a program "socketTest" to be a server. when my code is on the main activity, the output is ok. Now when I separate the codes on another class, the client message is just a blank space.

Comment: Yes you already told that. You dont have to repeat that. Further you are telling nothing extra and not reacting on my comment. This does not bring you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know what I'm missing. sorry for the inconvenience.

> separate class

```
public void SendSocket(String newMessage ) {
    if (newMessage != null) {
        try {
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            printwriter.write(newMessage + "\r\n"); // write the message to output stream
            printwriter.flush();

        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

> main class

```
View.OnClickListener SendOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {


        thread.SendSocket(textField.getText().toString());

    }

};
```